# How can we use Semantic-UI typings file in angular

Tags: angular, typescript-typings, dt

Many articles explains how to install typings for thirdy party libraries in Angular2/4, 
1. `npm install --save-dev jquery`,
2. `typing install dt~jquery`
3. `import * as $ from 'jquery';` in the .ts file

So I need someone to explain how we can install Semantic-UI in an Angular2/4 project using typing file: `typing install dt~semantic--save` in order to use a code like `$('.ui.accordion').accordion();`. When I try to do this it throw an error in the console,

> `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_jquery__(...).accordion is not a function at ...`

and the accordion is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I managed to make this work by, after installing the `jquery typings file` I installed the simantic-ui by `typing install dt~semantic --save`, and on top of the file: **src/typings.d.ts** I added this line: `/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts"/>` and that's all.

BTW: no need of `"declare var $: any;"` or `"import * as $ from 'jquery';"` in the .ts files.